# MultiSelectList shows one value from the IEnumerable given to it with multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form with a MultiSelectList and I'm using .Net validation to require a selection be made amongst required other vields. When I submit, the multiple selections are sent to the controller correctly but if requirements aren't met, ModelState is invalid, I return back to the form. I'm using the below line to set the ViewBag instance of the MultiSelectList with the selections that were made. The code seems to work. However, the view only displays a single selection, the first selection, not any of the others that were sent and returned.

`ViewBag.SelectedServiceLines = new MultiSelectList(db.LookUps.Where(lu => lu.RecordType == "ServLine"), "ID", "Description", funder.SelectedServiceLines.Select(i => i));`

If I step through the razor code in my view I can view the ViewData and see that there is a MultiSelectList and it does have all of the selections that were sent to the controller and then returned. But only one of those selections are displayed. Below is how I'm displaying the list. I can't figure out why only one item is being displayed and not the multiple that get sent back and are in the ViewBag as "SelectedItems" for the MultiSelectList.

`@Html.DropDownList("SelectedBusinessLines", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", @multiple = "multiple" })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `MultiSelectList` or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, depending on your choice:

```
// MultiSelectList approach
ViewBag.SelectedServiceLines = new MultiSelectList(db.LookUps.Where(lu => lu.RecordType == "ServLine"), "ID", "Description", funder.SelectedServiceLines.ToList());

// IEnumerable<SelectListItem> approach
ViewBag.SelectedServiceLines = db.LookUps.Where(lu => lu.RecordType == "ServLine")
                                         .Select(i => new SelectListItem() { 
                                                      Text = i.Description, 
                                                      Value = i.Id, 
                                                      Selected = funder.SelectedServiceLines.Contains(i.Id) 
                               }).ToList();
```

Then use [`ListBox[For]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.listboxfor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_SelectExtensions_ListBoxFor__2_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper___0__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___1___System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Web_Mvc_SelectListItem__System_Object_) helper instead of `DropDownList[For]` to create `<select>` element with `multiple` attribute:

```
@* MultiSelectList approach *@
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedBusinessLines, ViewBag.SelectedServiceLines as MultiSelectList, new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", @multiple = "multiple" })

@* IEnumerable<SelectListItem> approach *@
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedBusinessLines, ViewBag.SelectedServiceLines as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

Note that the `ViewBag` properties have dynamic type, you need to cast into respective type to avoid view rendering problem.

**Side note**

You may try create a `MultiSelectList` or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property inside viewmodel:

```
public MultiSelectList SelectedServiceLines { get; set; }
```

And populate it with same way as `ViewBag` mentioned above:

```
var model = new ViewModel(); // use your viewmodel class name

model.SelectedServiceLines = new MultiSelectList(db.LookUps.Where(lu => lu.RecordType == "ServLine"), "ID", "Description", funder.SelectedServiceLines.ToList());

return View(model);
```

Then use it with `ListBoxFor` helper, but this time without any cast unlike `ViewBag` does:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedBusinessLines, Model.SelectedServiceLines, new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

Comment: Both posts helped and I appreciate all the extra info. I switched over to `@Html.ListBoxFor<>` like you both suggested and then a few extras suggested and there have been two benefits from doing that. All selections are being displayed properly and no longer can someone select the placeholder as an option.

Comment: So thanks for the help. Quick question tho, some of your code examples are using `ViewBag.SelectedBusinessLines` and `Model.SelectedServiceLines` like this, `@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedBusinessLines, Model.SelectedServiceLines, new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", @multiple = "multiple" })` was that on purpose to use two different properties?

Comment: It's so weird I thought it was fixed. But what I didn't realize is that `ListBoxFor()` works in one instance while `DropDownList()` works in the other. One works as soon as I click the edit button and the other is blank. The working one goes blank and the other starts working after I try to submit changes and the `ModelState` is invalid so the model gets sent back to the view.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this instead? I've always used a `List<SelectListItem>` instead of a `MultiSelectList`:

```
// Use List<SelectListItem> instead
ViewBag.SelectedServiceLines = 
    db.LookUps
        .Where(lu => lu.RecordType == "ServLine")
        .Select(i => new SelectListItem() { Text = i.Description, Value = i.Id })
        .ToList();
```

I also suggest using a `ListBox` instead:

```
@Html.ListBox("SelectedBusinessLines", ViewBag.SelectedBusinessLines, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen-select", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

Comment: I will try. How did you add color to your edits? I've tried the three ticks like I've done before but haven't had success.

Comment: I tried using your query instead without using a ListBox, still only displayed one. This is an app that someone else made that I'm now managing so I'll have to see if I can easily change the MultiSelect to a ListBox.

Comment: If you indent all your code with 4 spaces it will format the code nicely. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Also I suggest adding a breakpoint immediately after you declare `ViewBag.SelectedServiceLines` - check that it indeed is a List of multiple SelectListItems and not just a single SelectListItem.

Comment: Man, it's the strangest thing. I can either `ListBoxFor()` to work and `DropDownList()` to work but here's what's strange. `DropDownList()` displays selected values the first time you click edit. After that it goes blank and `ListBoxFor()` will display all selected values. I have both of them rendering at the same time just for debugging purposes. I can't get one to work in both ways. One works when the other doesn't. I've ensured that values are in the `ViewData` and the view's `Model` the same within both actions. So I'm completely stumped as to what I'm not understanding.